# Library dependencies C++ project

Tags: c++, c, include, project, static-libraries

I have been struggling with this for quite a while and now i really need to figure this out. The problem is quite simple. I have a library `L` that depends on another library `D`, then i want to use the library `L` for my project. The problem is that when i include L's headers i get ( naturally ? ) errors "Cannot open include files that are part of `D`".

If i'm writing a project that needs to use `L` i don't want to care about its dependencies. A practical example would be a "Rendering framework" that wraps multiple graphics APIs. An user doesn't want to include the correct headers for the correct OS, because that's the libraries duty!.

I really hope i made myself clear and if this question has already been answered ( i bet it has ) would you please give me some keywords to search for ?.

Thank you for you time & happy coding :)

Comment: Sorry! You can't just _'don't want to care its dependencies'_ each and either way. To resolve include path dependencies there's e.g. GCC's `-I` option, to resolve library path dependencies there's `-L` option for the linker.

Comment: If L's headers require D's headers, then you need D's headers to use L.  Period.  End of story.  Can you modify the L library?  If so, it's possible to make L's headers NOT depend on Ds headers...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what if he can and all of us have been wrong? :-D

Comment: I don't get why downvoting me.. i was just trying to understand why when i link to SFML ( for instance ) i don't have to add OpenAL to my additional include directories. Sorry if i didn't explain myself correctly and sorry again if i entirely misunderstood your answer

Answer (score 0):

Link `L` statically to your "Rendering Framework" I recommend you read from IMB help: [When to use dynamic linking and static linking](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.prftungd/doc/prftungd/when_dyn_linking_static_linking.htm)

When you build `L` as static library you can "include" it "inside" your executable. So, you don't have to care about where is `L` any more. This has some disadvantages, for instance: If you want to change son piece of code that belongs to `L` you will have to recompile all your "Rendering Framework".

Said that:

Implement a top library `L`. Using some static libraries (such as `D`). And include all `*.h` files from `D` in the one you want the user to use.

Boost libraries use this pattern for code organization.

Comment: Maybe i didn't get it :( The point of the question is that : if i have a sample application that uses a rendering framework i don't want to manually include Direct3D or OpenGl, i want the framework to do that, and the framework will take care of linking against the libraries via #pragma comments. Is this a bad approach  ?

Comment: Hmmm, I don't like links referring to sources outside SO, unless these point to some 'official' standards publications. And even then, I'd rather seeing them cited here.

Comment: Ok, i get what you are trying to say, but if i include an header from "D" in "L" and then include "L" from my sample application i get errors ( naturally ? ) "Missing header from "D"". Is there any way to avoid this ? i do have correctly included the headers from "L"

Answer (score 0):

> [I]f i have a sample application that uses a rendering framework i don't want to manually include Direct3D or OpenGl [...]

If your rendering framework was correctly installed, its dependencies such as OpenGL must also have been correctly installed. In that case the framework's header files should find the dependencies' header files in the location that they expect them to be.